# How do I insert a zero in front of single-digit months and days in my calendar popup?

Tags: javascript, string

I am including Javascript code that is used to pop up a calendar. The problem with the code is that I want a '0' to be inserted in front of the month or day if the month lies between 1--9 and days between 1--9 in the calendar.
The following is the script.  Can anybody guide me to the modifications?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var daysInMonth = new Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
var days = new Array("S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S");

today = new getToday(); 
var element_id;

function getDays(month, year) 
{
    // Test for leap year when February is selected.
    if (1 == month)
        return ((0 == year % 4) && (0 != (year % 100))) ||
            (0 == year % 400) ? 29 : 28;
    else
        return daysInMonth[month];
}

function getToday()
{
    // Generate today's date.
    this.now = new Date();
    this.year = this.now.getFullYear() ; // Returned year XXXX
    this.month = this.now.getMonth();
    this.day = this.now.getDate();
}


function newCalendar() 
{
    var parseYear = parseInt(document.all.year  [document.all.year.selectedIndex].text);

    var newCal = new Date(parseYear , document.all.month.selectedIndex, 1);
    var day = -1;
    var startDay = newCal.getDay();
    var daily = 0; 

    today = new getToday(); // 1st call
    if ((today.year == newCal.getFullYear() ) &&   (today.month == newCal.getMonth()))
       day = today.day;
    // Cache the calendar table's tBody section, dayList.
    var tableCal = document.all.calendar.tBodies.dayList;

    var intDaysInMonth =
       getDays(newCal.getMonth(), newCal.getFullYear() );

    for (var intWeek = 0; intWeek < tableCal.rows.length;  intWeek++)
           for (var intDay = 0;
             intDay < tableCal.rows[intWeek].cells.length;
             intDay++)
     {
          var cell = tableCal.rows[intWeek].cells[intDay];

          // Start counting days.
          if ((intDay == startDay) && (0 == daily))
             daily = 1;

          // Highlight the current day.
          cell.style.color = (day == daily) ? "red" : "";
          if(day == daily)
          {
                document.all.todayday.innerText= "Today: " +  day + "/" + 
                    (newCal.getMonth()+1) + "/" + newCal.getFullYear() ;
          }
          // Output the day number into the cell.
          if ((daily > 0) && (daily <= intDaysInMonth))
             cell.innerText = daily++;
          else
             cell.innerText = "";
       }

}

     function getTodayDay()
     {
                document.all[element_id].value = today.year + "/" + (today.month+1) + 
                    "/" + today.day; 
                //document.all.calendar.style.visibility="hidden";
                document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
                document.all.year.selectedIndex =100;   
                document.all.month.selectedIndex = today.month; 
     }

        function getDate() 
         {
            // This code executes when the user clicks on a day
            // in the calendar.
            if ("TD" == event.srcElement.tagName)
               // Test whether day is valid.
               if ("" != event.srcElement.innerText)
               { 
                 var mn = document.all.month.selectedIndex+1;
                 var Year = document.all.year [document.all.year.selectedIndex].text;
                document.all[element_id].value=Year +"-"+mn+"-"+event.srcElement.innerText;
                 document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
             }
         }

function GetBodyOffsetX(el_name, shift)
{
    var x;
    var y;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    var elem = document.all[el_name];
    do 
    {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
        if (elem.tagName == "BODY")
            break;
        elem = elem.offsetParent; 
    } while  (1 > 0);

    shift[0] = x;
    shift[1] = y;
    return  x;
}   

function SetCalendarOnElement(el_name)
{
    if (el_name=="") 
    el_name = element_id;
    var shift = new Array(2);
    GetBodyOffsetX(el_name, shift);
    document.all.calendar.style.pixelLeft  = shift[0]; //  - document.all.calendar.offsetLeft;
    document.all.calendar.style.pixelTop = shift[1] + 25 ;
}

function ShowCalendar(elem_name)
{
        if (elem_name=="")
        elem_name = element_id;

        element_id  = elem_name; // element_id is global variable
        newCalendar();
        SetCalendarOnElement(element_id);
        //document.all.calendar.style.visibility = "visible";
        document.all.calendar.style.display="inline";
}

function HideCalendar()
{
    //document.all.calendar.style.visibility="hidden";
    document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
}

function toggleCalendar(elem_name)
{
    //if (document.all.calendar.style.visibility == "hidden")
    if(document.all.calendar.style.display=="none")
        ShowCalendar(elem_name);
    else 
        HideCalendar();
}
-->
</script>

<style>
.today {COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold}
.days {COLOR: navy; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: center}
.dates {COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 10pt}
</style>
</head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFF8DC"> 
     <h5>Diesel Generators</h5><br><br>
         <br>
             <br>
                 <script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG1');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG2');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG3');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG4');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG5');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select  All<br/>

<form method=POST action="DGUsageServlet">

<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG1">DG1
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG2">DG2
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG3">DG3
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG4">DG4
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG5">DG5

<br>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="StartDate">
    <a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="toggleCalendar('StartDate')">StartDate</a>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="EndDate">
     <a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="toggleCalendar('EndDate')">EndDate</a>
<input name=plotgraph value=plotgraph align="CENTER" type=submit>
</form>
<TABLE bgColor=#ffffff border=1 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=3 id=calendar style="DISPLAY: none; POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: 4">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD colSpan=7 vAlign=center>
    <!-- Month combo box -->
    <SELECT id=month onchange=newCalendar()> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Output months into the document.
        // Select current month.
        for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < months.length; intLoop++)
            document.write("<OPTION " + (today.month == intLoop ? "Selected" : "") + ">" + months[intLoop]);
        </SCRIPT>
    </SELECT> 
    <!-- Year combo box -->
    <SELECT id=year onchange=newCalendar()> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Output years into the document.
        // Select current year.
        for (var intLoop = 1900; intLoop < 2028; intLoop++)
            document.write("<OPTION " + (today.year == intLoop ? "Selected" : "") + ">" + intLoop);
        </SCRIPT>
    </SELECT> 

    </TD>
  </TR>

  <TR class=days>
    <!-- Generate column for each day. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Output days.
    for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < days.length; intLoop++)
        document.write("<TD>" + days[intLoop] + "</TD>");
    </SCRIPT>
  </TR>


  <TBODY class=dates id=dayList onclick="getDate('')" vAlign=center>
  <!-- Generate grid for individual days. -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    for (var intWeeks = 0; intWeeks < 6; intWeeks++)
    {
        document.write("<TR>");
        for (var intDays = 0; intDays < days.length; intDays++)
            document.write("<TD>" +intDays+ "</TD>");

        document.write("</TR>");
    }
  </SCRIPT>

  <!-- Generate today day. --></TBODY>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class=today colSpan=5 id=todayday onclick=getTodayDay()></TD>
    <TD align=right colSpan=2><A href="javascript:HideCalendar();"><SPAN style="COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 10px"><B>Hide</B></SPAN></A></TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>

</TABLE>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.write() ? it's 2009.....

Comment: Just a few more leftovers from the 20th century: document.all, inline event handlers, inline styles, "javascript" links.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the way you are writing the script that it is ever going to work as intended. Try looking on google for a pre-made solution. There is no shame in that.

https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/JavascriptCalendar

http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENUS302&=&q=javascript+popup+calendar&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nelson,

[This](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/) is one of the best javascript date picker solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a zero string to the front of it, and return two last characters using .substring(-2,2), like so:

```
var iv="3";
alert(("0"+iv).substring(-2,2));
iv=1;
alert(("0"+iv).substring(-2,2));
iv=2;
alert(("0"+iv).substring(-2,2));
```

It does not matter if the input is a string or digit.